# Accessing global variable from zshrc in PHP

Tags: php, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I had this all working on another machine using .bash_profile but can't get this to work with z shell using the .zshrc file. This is how my .zshrc is set up:

`export foo="bar"`

If I echo foo in my terminal, I see this:

```
% echo $foo
bar
```

But, when I run this PHP script, nothing shows up:

```
<?php

global $foo;

echo "this is my global verable: < {$foo} >";
```

Hoping something minor and stupid I'm missing here, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Never used it but I doubt that `global $foo` is the same variable as the one in your shell. Would [getenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) help?

Comment: This is known as an environment variable.  PHP globals are not going to be accessing the same memory as your system's environment variables.   While you could use getenv, environment variables shouldn't be used in place of input.   If you want to pass data to your PHP script, just use https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: `$_ENV['foo']`.

Comment: You confuse the idea of a _global variable_ with an _environment variable_.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job - Thank's y'all!

```
<?php

$baz = getenv("foo");

echo $baz;

?>
```